# Building histogram from a dict without having to iterate over the keys

Tags: python, dictionary, histogram

I have a dict containing numpy array of varying length:

```
MyDcit= {0:array([[ 15.        ,   3.89678216],
                   [ 36.        ,   9.49245167],
                   [ 53.        ,   3.82997799],
                   [ 83.        ,   5.25727272],
                   [ 86.        ,   8.76663208]]),
         1:array([[  4.        ,   4.1171155 ],
                  [ 16.        ,  12.68122196],
                  [ 31.        ,   8.64805222],
                  [ 37.        ,  6.07202959]]),
         2:array([]),...,
         90:array([[  1.        ,   1.        ],
                   [ 24.        ,   8.14221573],
                   [ 27.        ,   7.36309862]])}
```

I would like to obtain an histogram of all the values in the dict. The solution I have now is to iterate over the keys in the dict and fill a numpy array with an histogram of fixed length:

```
for KeysElements in MyDict.keys():
     hist,bins = numpy.histogram(np.asarray(MyDict[KeysElements])[:,1],50)
     numpy_hist[KeysElements,:] = hist
```

I then sum up all the histograms over the fist dimension of the numpy array to obtain the histogram of all the keys of the initial dict:

```
Total_hist = numpy.sum(numpy_hist,axis=0)
```

The problems with this solutions is that I do not knwo how to handle the bins which change for each iteration, so my question is: are there any possibilities to achieve this without having to built histograms in a loop?

Thanks for any advices or links.

Greg

Comment: is it `numpy.histogram(np.asarray(MyDict[KeysElements])[:,1],50)` ?

Comment: well I want the histogram on the second column of the numpy array, so therefore numpy.histogram(np.asarray(MyDict[KeysElements])[:,1],50)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to use the MyDict index values or the 0th values in the 2nd axis of your np arrays. If this is the case then you could add all the numpy arrays together and do the histogram on that

```
import numpy as np

MyDict = {0:np.array([[ 15.        ,   3.89678216],
                   [ 36.        ,   9.49245167],
                   [ 53.        ,   3.82997799],
                   [ 83.        ,   5.25727272],
                   [ 86.        ,   8.76663208]]),
         1:np.array([[  4.        ,   4.1171155 ],
                  [ 16.        ,  12.68122196],
                  [ 31.        ,   8.64805222],
                  [ 37.        ,  6.07202959]]),
         2:np.array([]),
         90:np.array([[  1.        ,   1.        ],
                   [ 24.        ,   8.14221573],
                   [ 27.        ,   7.36309862]])}
np_array = np.array([]).reshape(0,2)

for i in MyDict:
  a = MyDict[i]
  if len(a.shape) == 2 and a.shape[1] == 2:
    np_array = np.append(np_array, MyDict[i], axis=0)
print(np.histogram(np_array, 50))
```

Comment: Hei, Ok it does it. Thanks.